# Trying to create a categories and sub categorise drop down menu

Tags: php

I am trying to create a categories and sub categories drop down menu using PHP, I have created two tables = a table called categories which hold id of the categories and the name and I created a sub categories which hold the id of the sub categories. The id of the main categories and the name of the sub categories, but I am only getting the same sub categories names for all the main  categories and its not linking to the actual name that I set

**Model**

```
<?php
class Post{

private $db;
public function __construct(){
  $this->db = new Database;
 }

 public function getcat(){
   $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM categoires');

   $results = $this->db->resultSet();
   return $results;
 }


public function getsubcat(){

$cat = $this->getcat();

$id = $cat[0]->id;


$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM sub_cat WHERE 
cat_id =:cat_id');




 $this->db->bind(':cat_id', $id);
 $results = $this->db->resultSet();
 return $results;

}

}
```

**controller**

```
     public function index(){





     $cats = $this->postModel->getcat();

     $sub_cats = $this->postModel->getsubcat();



      $data = [

               'cats'=> $cats,
               'sub_cats' => $sub_cats
                 ];

    $this->view('posts/index', $data);
  }
```

**view**

```
    <?php foreach($data['cats'] as $cats) : ?> 

<li>


 <?php echo $cats->cat_name; ?>


     <?php foreach($data['sub_cats'] as $sub_cats) : ?> 
      <ul>
           <li><?php echo $sub_cats->sub_name; ?></li>
       </ul>
      <?php endforeach; ?>


</li>


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Database class**

I have created this class to bind value and create prepared statements

```
<?php
class Database {
private $host = DB_HOST;
private $user = DB_USER;
private $pass = DB_PASS;
private $dbname = DB_NAME;

private $dbh;
private $stmt;
private $error;

public function __construct(){
  // Set DSN
   $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
    $options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
  );

  // Create PDO instance
  try{
    $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
  } catch(PDOException $e){
    $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    echo $this->error;
  }
}

// Prepare statement with query
public function query($sql){
  $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
}

// Bind values
public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
  if(is_null($type)){
    switch(true){
      case is_int($value):
        $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
        break;
      case is_bool($value):
        $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
        break;
      case is_null($value):
        $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
        break;
      default:
        $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
    }
  }

  $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}

// Execute the prepared statement
public function execute(){
  return $this->stmt->execute();
}

// Get result set as array of objects
public function resultSet(){
  $this->execute();
  return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

// Get single record as object
public function single(){
  $this->execute();
  return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

// Get row count
public function rowCount(){
  return $this->stmt->rowCount();
}
}
```

So based on the code that i made it seems that its only getting the first id from the categories table and looping the same name

[categoires Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlnOd.png)

[sub_cat table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOy3A.png)

[The output i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1opI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem in your getsubcat() function.

```
$cat = $this->getcat();

$id = $cat[0]->id;

$cat_name = $cat[0]->cat_name;

$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM sub_cat WHERE 
cat_id =:cat_id');

$this->db->bind(':cat_name', $cat_name);

$this->db->bind(':cat_id', $id);
```

You select all categories with getcat() which is ok but then right after you select only the first row :

```
$id = $cat[0]->id;

$cat_name = $cat[0]->cat_name;
```

So that's why you get the same result for this specific query no matter is the category. And all your sub-cat are the same and equal to the sub-cat of the first category.

**Edit with example :**

```
public function getCategoriesWithSubCategories(){

    $categoriesWithSubCategories = array();

    $categories = $this->getcat();

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $this->db->query('SELECT sub_name FROM sub_cat WHERE cat_id =:cat_id');
        $this->db->bind(':cat_id', $category->id);
        $subCategories = $this->db->resultSet();

        $subCategories_labels = array();
        foreach ($subCategories as $subCategory) {
            array_push($subCategories_labels, $subCategory->sub_name);
        } // end of subcategories loop

        $categoriesWithSubCategories[$category->cat_name] = $subCategories_labels;

    } // end of categories loop

    return $categoriesWithSubCategories;

} // end of function
```

Update your controller to use this function only. So you'll be dealing with a single array.

Then your output will be something like this :

```
    foreach ($data['array_with_results'] as $cats => $subcats) { 
        echo '<li>' . $cats;

        foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
            echo '<li><ul>' . $subcat . '</ul></li>';
        }

        echo '</li>';
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but if remove the [] from the $cat[0] i will get an error that says Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: I added an example too ;)

Comment: i have tried your answer and i am getting Warning
: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Which foreach ?

Comment: foreach ($data['sub_cats'] as $cats => $subcats) {

Comment: I just saw i forgot to return the array in my function, that will probably fix this (i edited once again my answer)

Comment: Thank you so much it worked ...is it possible you can show me if u can pass id of the sub categories and the id of the categories

Comment: You can do it by customizing the array and adapt your output depending on this array. But i guess that's not the best place to develop this new question. Btw don't forget to close this post choosing the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getsubcat(){

$cat = $this->getcat();

$id = $cat[0]->id;

$cat_name = $cat[0]->cat_name;

$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM sub_cat WHERE cat_name = :cat_name and 
cat_id =:cat_id');


 $this->db->bind(':cat_name', $cat_name);

 $this->db->bind(':cat_id', $id);
 $results = $this->db->resultSet();
 return $results;

}
```

```
$id = $cat[0]->id;

$cat_name = $cat[0]->cat_name;
```

here you set $cat[0]
so it get only the frist one

add a foreach or for

```
$cat = $this->getcat();

for($i=0 ; i<count($cat);$i++){

$id = $cat[$i]->id;

$cat_name = $cat[$i]->cat_name;
$cat = $this->getcat();

// query ... fetch ...
// save as $array[$i]=$results
}
// return $array
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but if remove the [] from the $cat[0] i will get an error that says Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: add a for to incr the 0 // exelple : // $cat[$i]

Comment: @J.Doe i add the exemple

Comment: i have edited my code according to your answer and i am getting error which says Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$sub_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\shareposts\app\views\posts\index.php